# Using DateTime method in ruby

Tags: ruby, datetime

I'm developing an application using Visual Ruby. In that I'm fetching a date from a dropdown like below:

```
check_to_in_1 = @builder.get_object("cellrenderertext7")
```

then I split this date using the `split` method:

```
date_split = check_to_in_1.text.to_s.split("/")
```

I do this split because I want to convert the date from `String` to `DateTime` format, after splitting i print the values like below:

```
puts "#{date_split[2]}"  # => 05
puts "#{date_split[1]}"  # => 10
puts "#{date_split[0]}"  # => 2013
```

Now I passed this value to the `DateTime.new` method to convert it to `DateTime`:

```
check_to_in_time_converted = DateTime.new(date_split[0], 
                                          date_split[1], date_split[2])
```

Now here I got this error:

```
C:/Users/abhiram/visualruby/examples/fedena/bin/SendAbsentees.rb:213:in `new': undefined method `div' for "05":String
 from C:/Users/abhiram/visualruby/examples/fedena/bin/SendAbsentees.rb:213:in `button1_clicked'
 from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/gtk2-1.2.1-x86-mingw32/lib/gtk2/base.rb:95:in `call'
 from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/gtk2-1.2.1-x86-mingw32/lib/gtk2/base.rb:95:in `block in __connect_signals__'
 from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vrlib-0.0.33/lib/GladeGUI.rb:331:in `call'
 from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vrlib-0.0.33/lib/GladeGUI.rb:331:in `main'
 from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vrlib-0.0.33/lib/GladeGUI.rb:331:in `show_window'
 from C:/Users/abhiram/visualruby/examples/fedena/bin/SendAbsentees.rb:99:in `show'
 from C:/Users/abhiram/visualruby/examples/fedena/bin/Control.rb:36:in `button2_clicked'
 from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/gtk2-1.2.1-x86-mingw32/lib/gtk2/base.rb:95:in `call'
```

I don't know what to do from here, could anyone help me to come out of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can read in the calls stack trace, `DateTime.new` is sending the method `div` to the string `"05"` that is not defined:

```
[...]/bin/SendAbsentees.rb:213:in `new': undefined method `div' for "05":String
```

That is because `DateTime.new` expects integers as arguments. You have to convert to integers the elements of `date_split` before passing them to `DateTime.new`:

```
DateTime.new(*date_split.map(&:to_i))
```

Even better you can do it without splitting the string, using `DateTime.strptime` instead of `DateTime.new`, like this:

```
DateTime.strptime(check_to_in_1.text.to_s, '%Y/%m/%d')
# => #<DateTime: 2013-05-10T00:00:00+00:00 ((2456423j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

I assumed your dates are in the format YEAR/MONTH/DAY, if instead they are in the format YEAR/DAY/MONTH you just have to swap `%m` and `%d` in the second argument to `strptime`.

Comment: thanks alot for saving my time.. converting it to integer as you said did the job.. :)